# Perl: How to iterate over arrays in multiple objects and extract values from webservice

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach

I request a web service and get a JSON response:

```
{
   "timestamp" : "2019-06-11T08:04:35Z",
   "version" : "0.5",
   "document" : [
      {
         "href" : "http://opac.sub.uni-goettingen.de/DB=1/PPNSET?PPN=1629107239",
         "item" : [
            {
               "href" : "http://opac.sub.uni-goettingen.de/DB=1/PPNSET?PPN=1629107239",
               "label" : "40 623 a",
               "id" : "http://uri.gbv.de/document/opac-de-7:epn:3421084610",
               "available" : [
                  {
                     "service" : "presentation"
                  }
               ],
               "unavailable" : [
                  {
                     "service" : "loan"
                  },
                  {
                     "service" : "interloan"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "href" : "http://opac.sub.uni-goettingen.de/DB=1/PPNSET?PPN=1629107239",
               "label" : "40 623 b",
               "id" : "http://uri.gbv.de/document/opac-de-7:epn:342108467X",
               "available" : [
                  {
                     "service" : "presentation"
                  }
               ],
               "unavailable" : [
                  {
                     "service" : "loan"
                  },
                  {
                     "service" : "interloan"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         "id" : "http://uri.gbv.de/document/opac-de-7:ppn:1629107239"
      }
   ],
   "institution" : {
      "href" : "http://www.sub.uni-goettingen.de",
      "content" : "Niedersächsische Staats- und Universitätsbibliothek Göttingen",
      "id" : "http://uri.gbv.de/organization/isil/DE-7"
   }
}
```

Then I parse the JSON with Perls Dumper::Data module:

```
my $data = decode_json($resultJson);
print Dumper($data);
```

It looks like:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'document' => [
                          {
                            'item' => [
                                        {
                                          'available' => [
                                                           {
                                                             'service' => 'presentation'
                                                           }
                                                         ],
                                          'id' => 'http://uri.gbv.de/document/opac-de-7:epn:3421084610',
                                          'href' => 'http://opac.sub.uni-goettingen.de/DB=1/PPNSET?PPN=1629107239',
                                          'label' => '40 623 a',
                                          'unavailable' => [
                                                             {
                                                               'service' => 'loan'
                                                             },
                                                             {
                                                               'service' => 'interloan'
                                                             }
                                                           ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                          'available' => [
                                                           {
                                                             'service' => 'presentation'
                                                           }
                                                         ],
                                          'unavailable' => [
                                                             {
                                                               'service' => 'loan'
                                                             },
                                                             {
                                                               'service' => 'interloan'
                                                             }
                                                           ],
                                          'id' => 'http://uri.gbv.de/document/opac-de-7:epn:342108467X',
                                          'label' => '40 623 b',
                                          'href' => 'http://opac.sub.uni-goettingen.de/DB=1/PPNSET?PPN=1629107239'
                                        }
                                      ],
                            'id' => 'http://uri.gbv.de/document/opac-de-7:ppn:1629107239',
                            'href' => 'http://opac.sub.uni-goettingen.de/DB=1/PPNSET?PPN=1629107239'
                          }
                        ],
          'institution' => {
                             'content' => "Nieders\x{e4}chsische Staats- und Universit\x{e4}tsbibliothek G\x{f6}ttingen",
                             'id' => 'http://uri.gbv.de/organization/isil/DE-7',
                             'href' => 'http://www.sub.uni-goettingen.de'
                           },
          'timestamp' => '2019-06-11T08:04:35Z',
          'version' => '0.5'
        };
```

I would like to display the availability of each item, but I'm having a hard time iterating through the arrays inside the objects. My actual code looks like:

```
my $availability = $data->{document}[0]->{item}[0]->{available};

foreach my $key (@{$availability}) {
    if (($key->{'service'}) eq "loan") {
        print $rueckgabe = "Loan: available.\n";
    } elsif (($key->{'service'}) eq "presentation") {
        print $rueckgabe = "Presentation: available.\n";
    } elsif (($key->{'service'}) eq "interloan") {
        print $rueckgabe = "ILL: available.\n";
    } 
}
```

My expected result would be:

Item 1: Loan: available.

Item 2: Loan: available.

Comment: If I was reviewing your code at `$work` in a German company I would tell you that mixing German and English variable names is confusing. Stick to English so your company is able to hire foreigners that don't speak German. Especially if you work for a university.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was just copy'n pasting it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the items, for each item, iterate over the availabilities.

```
for my $i (0 .. $#{ $data->{document}[0]{item} }) {
    print 'Item ', $i + 1, ': ';
    for my $availability ($data->{document}[0]{item}[$i]{available}) {
        for my $key (@$availability) {
            print { interloan => 'ILL' }->{ $key->{service} } || ucfirst $key->{service},
                ": available\n";
        }
    }
}
```